# Ubuntu 22.04 sound crackling after computer upgrade

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I upgraded my computer to cpu: 7800X3d and gpu: rx 7900XTX. However after the update my dualboot hdmi output hasn't been working properly on the 22.04 LTS. The sound crackles weirdly on hdmi output. Via headset things run smoothly. I've tried pretty much everything I find on the internet but can't find a solution.

On Ubuntu 23.10 the sound problem is mild. The crackling you hear only in the video only appears when some new audio starts and only max 1s. After that it's like everything works perfectly.

On my current 22.04 machine uname -a:

> Linux lauri-System-Product-Name 6.5.0-25-generic #25~22.04.1-Ubuntu
> SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Feb 20 16:09:15 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64
> GNU/Linux

I've also tried using displayport cable and the same issue exists. So the problem isn't in the port nor the cable. Doubt it's the monitor since everything works perfectly on Windows 11.

Video: https://youtube.com/shorts/EM9WmJiO9mM

Edit: I'm not quite sure what I've managed to change but now the status is as follows:
https://youtube.com/shorts/913Thc_Kpmg